# Allow loading http sites in UIWebView without allowing arbitrary loads app-wide

Tags: ios, uiwebview

As part of my app, I want users to be able to share and open links using UIWebViews. Of course, this doesn't just work for http links, because iOS by default refuses to open insecure connections. I know I can bypass this by adding `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true` to the PList, but this is not generally recommended, as it opens up the entire app to vulnerabilities. However, the folks advising against it don't usually provide any alternative recommendations. One alternative I have come across is to whitelist specific domains. This won't help me, because I want users to be able to share any website they want.

Is there a way to bypass this security measure only for specific instances of UIWebViewControllers? Or would that be defeating the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Which kinds of url your UIWebViewControllers will request? I think you can add a white list when some url is requested in UIWebView.

Comment: Like I said in the question, users can add any sites, so a whitelist is not feasible.

Comment: I mean you can add a whitelist before request: first step you need get users' url, and add this url to whitelist. After request you can delete this url from whitelist. Here is some example [add white list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-commits/201304.mbox/%3C499ec9c7235a4d2faf5ae0373fbc7a38@git.apache.org%3E) by code

Comment: Oh, is it possible to do that programmatically at runtime? Would you mind editing your answer and adding some code that demonstrates this? The link you provided is pretty hard to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, I'm not sure it doesn't defeat the purpose of disabling NSAllowsArbitaryLoads. In theory it would be better in that you're only allowing connections through specific UIWebViews and nowhere else in the app.

Whitelisting urls that are entered could work, but again if you allow users to enter their own whitelisted urls, it begs the question why introduce the extra step, you might as well enable arbitary loads in the first place.

Either take the hit and expose yourself, or abide by the recommendation from Apple. I reckon a lot of apps allow arbitary loads, but it's not great practice. Check out the security [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). It also depends on what you want your app to do - is there a legitimate case to access non https sites etc.

Answer (score 0):

While `UIWebView`s aren't allowed to open http sites (without explicitly bypassing the restriction somehow), looks like`SFSafariViewController`s are. They're not exactly the same -- the former is a view while the latter is a controller, which affords far less customization -- but if your use case is opening websites, then this could be a good fit.